# How to set json data to razor controls in jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, razor, jqgrid

I have a razor view which contains both field controls and  grid for the fields in the same page. If I click the edit button in the grid, then I want to get the row data and set to the fields for editing option.

I got the grid's row data by using the rowId like

```
 var rowData = $('#CorpGroupSearchGrid').getRowData(rowId);
```

Now I want to load the rowData to the model or populate it on the field controls. I did it like following but it is not working. I don't know how doing it, please anybody help.

```
$("#CorpGroupAll").html(rowData);
```

The 'CorpGroupAll' is the Id of the parent div tag of the field controls.

Comment: Can you explain your question in more detail with some code.

Comment: i think you have to create html of rowData as fields control. and add generated html to 'CorpGroupAll'

Comment: `rowData` contains the object with the data, which represent the model and not HTML fragment. Thus you can't use `$("#CorpGroupAll").html(rowData);` to fill the data in the form. You should enumerate the properties of `rowData` and search for elements inside of the form which have `name` attribute equal to the property name of `rowData`. You should set the value of the property to the element. You should examine the form `#CorpGroupAll` and compare the fields to `name` property of `colModel`, which should be the properties of `rowData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowData` is a javscript array with data about required row so clearly `$("#CorpGroupAll").html(rowData)` can not work. if you want to pass the values of rowData to custom editors that you have on your page you need to do it manually, property by property. For example assuming that your row has a `Name` column and you have an input field that is used for editing this Name value with id `editor_Name` then you need to do something like:

```
$('#editor_Name').val(rowData.Name);
```

If you manage to create an input ids with some pattern for example `editor_{Name of property}` you can try to automate this task with some JavaScript:

```
var props = Object.keys(rowData);
for (var propName in props)
{
   var id = '#editor_' + propName;
   var $input = $(id);
   if($input.length === 1)
   {
      $input.val(rowData[propName]);
   }   
}
```

Comment: Now I used Ajax function to retrieve the record and Inside the success(data ) function, how to load

Comment: the code that I added maps values from rowData to input fields for all the properties. But the constraint is that ids for those input fields have to be from the following pattern: '#editor_' + {propertyName}

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `json` data to your inputs in `afterShowForm` event of `jqgrid` edit form. Hide the edit form immediately after opening. Then set value of your inputs by the values of selected row like following. Hope this will help you.

```
afterShowForm: function(formid){
    $('#editmodCorpGroupSearchGrid').find('.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick').click();
    var rowId = $('#CorpGroupSearchGrid').jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    var rowData = $('#CorpGroupSearchGrid').getRowData(rowId);

    // assume `id` and `name` are the ids of your inputs
    $('#id').val(rowData.id);
    $('#name').val(rowData.name);
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/azim101/v0dq8pcr/1/)

Comment: `$("#CorpGroupAll").html(rowData)` replace the whole content of `#CorpGroupAll`. You can do it with a logical function depending on your `model` & `grid` to do that. @MdAslam

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your priority is to assign the values to your controls.

You may have to set the id of the respective controls matching the jqgrid column index(name). If then you can put something like below:

```
$.each(rowData, function (i) {
            $("#" + rowData[i].name).text(rowData[i].value);
        });
```

Comment: It shows the "rowData" is undefined. If i give the data instead of rowData it accepted but again it shows name property is undefined. What to do ?

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you need a partial view to hold the model elements from the row and then populate the partial view with rowData.

Comment: Views(Partial views) are rendered on server while `var rowData = $('#CorpGroupSearchGrid').getRowData(rowId);` is a client side code